# Why I can not see the icon pics in Angular mat-icon-button?

Tags: html, angular, button, icons, angular-material2

I found this part of code in an Angular project and I wanted to add it to my program too:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <a mat-icon-button class="btn-google-plus" href="http://google.com/+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a>
  <a mat-icon-button class="btn-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a>
  <a mat-icon-button class="btn-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></a>
  <a mat-icon-button class="btn-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
  <a mat-icon-button class="btn-youtube" href="http://youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-lg"></i></a>
  <a mat-icon-button class="btn-mail" href="mailto:"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg"></i></a>
</div>
```

But the problem is that I can not see the pictures(symbols) of each icon inside of it and it shows icons with no pics in my app! What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should do: <a  href=""><mat-icon>theNameOfTheIcon</mat-icon></a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are used a **Font Awesome** Icon in your code so you need to add the library in your angular setup. Please refer to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome) link on how you can use the Font Awesome library in your setup.

Or else you can just call the external stylesheet in your index.html then it will work fine also. Please refer to the external stylesheet URL.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Hope this helps!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code `<i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></I>` inform that you want to show icons from **Awesome Font**

If you want to do that you should add import this font in your app e.g in: `index.html`.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

More info on how to use this font you will find [here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/)

Answer (score 0):

Doing the Angular course on Coursera in 2022, I faced this same problem. The code in the question is identical to the code in the course, so I assume OP faced it in that course as well.

Here is a solution that is specific to this question in the context of the conFusion web site developed for this course:

In `src/_variables.scss`, I was able to fix this problem by setting

```
$fa-font-path : '../fonts';
```

instead of `../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts` as instructed.

It appears that when you have this import in `styles.scss` in an Angular project:

```
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
```

the `$fa-font-path` variable is interpreted as being relative to where the Font Awesome scss files are all located, which is where that variable is actually used, rather than relative to where your `styles.scss` file itself is located.

I am doing the course with Angular 14.2. I assume the instructor's instructions worked as is where he recorded the course in 2018 or so, but things have changes with SCSS since then.